# Load streamingassets from non coroutine method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class ImageLoader : MonoBehaviour  {
private Texture2D _texInMemory;  
public Texture2D GetImage(string fileName)
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadImage(fileName));  
    return _texInMemory;
}

IEnumerator LoadImage(string fileName)
{
    var path = somestring;
    WWW uri = new WWW(path);
    yield return uri;

    _texInMemory = uri.texture;`enter code here`
}
}
```

My question is what line i need to add in `GetImage` method / `ImageLoader` class so another script can get _texInMemory from `GetImage` Method ?

Answer (score 1):

Add more methods and a boolean variable to it. The boolean variable will be set when the coroutine function has finished executing.

You will then check if the boolean variable is true before loading it.

```
public class ImageLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool imageDone = false;
    private Texture2D _texInMemory = null;

    public Texture2D getImage()
    {
        return _texInMemory;
    }

    public bool imageReady()
    {
        return imageDone;
    }

    public void retrieveImage(string fileName)
    {
        if (!imageDone)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error: Image is still retrieving");
            return;
        }

        imageDone = false;
        StartCoroutine(loadImage(fileName));
    }

    private IEnumerator loadImage(string fileName)
    {
        var path = somestring;
        WWW uri = new WWW(path);
        yield return uri;
        _texInMemory = uri.texture;

        imageDone = true;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

*From a normal function*:

```
void Update()
{
    GameObject obj = new GameObject("obj");
    ImageLoader imgLd = obj.AddComponent<ImageLoader>();

    //then
    imgLd.retrieveImage("Your Image");

    //Check if image has finished loading
    if (imgLd.imageReady())
    {
        //Retrieve image
        Texture2D loadedImg = imgLd.getImage();
    }
}
```

*Note that*

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject("obj");
ImageLoader imgLd = obj.AddComponent<ImageLoader>();
imgLd.loadImage("Your Image");
```

*must be called **once** only in the Update function. You can keep calling the rest of the code until `imgLd.imageReady()` returns `true`.*

*Or from a coroutine function*:

```
IEnumerator test()
{
    GameObject obj = new GameObject("obj");
    ImageLoader imgLd = obj.AddComponent<ImageLoader>();

    //then
    imgLd.retrieveImage("Your Image");

    //Wait unitl image is loaded
    while (imgLd.imageReady())
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Retrieve image
    Texture2D loadedImg = imgLd.getImage();
}
```